# Generating in-memory zip file with excel sheets at Servlet side

Tags: java, excel, stream, zip, apache-poi

Here basically i am trying to send zip file with excel sheets from server to client.

**Approach 1 : My Servlet code**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new  ZipOutputStream(bos);

for(Map.Entry<String, List<Data>> entry : DatasMap.entrySet())
{
   String fileName = entry.getKey();
   List<Data> excelData = entry.getValue();

   // The below code constructs the workbook and returns it
   SXSSFWorkbook workBook = getWorkBook(fileName, excelData);
   ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName );
   zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
   workBook.write(zos);

   zos.closeEntry(); // getting error at this line
}
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyApp-server] in context with path [/myapp-server] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
     at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.ensureOpen(ZipOutputStream.java:82)
     at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:231)
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new  ZipOutputStream(bos);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

for(Map.Entry<String, List<Data>> entry : DatasMap.entrySet())
{
   String fileName = entry.getKey();
   List<Data> excelData = entry.getValue();

   // The below code constructs the workbook and returns it
   SXSSFWorkbook workBook = getWorkBook(fileName, excelData);
   ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName );
   zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
   workBook.write(bos);
   bos.writeTo(zos)

   zos.closeEntry(); // this line works perfectly in this case
}
zos.close();
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

//setting content-type and zip file name
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Templates.zip");
out.write(bytes);
out.flush();
```

Approach 2 works fine, But when i try to open zip file at the client side, I gets error saying `error extracting`

[image]

I am not sure whether `excel sheet` is corrupted or any other server side stream issue. If any body has some helpful thoughts/ideas please share with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second attempt fails, because you are mixing zipped content and unzipped content by directly writing the workbook to the underlying `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Therefore the generated zip file is screwed up.

The first attempt fails because `workBook.write` closes the `ZipOutputStream` and you get the `Stream closed` exception when you write the second entry.

But you can prevent this closing of the stream. Create a helper `OutputStream`  class which cannot be closed:

```
public class NonCloseableOutputStream extends java.io.FilterOutputStream {
    public NonCloseableOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override public void close() throws IOException {
        flush();
    }
}
```

and pass an instance of that class to the workbook:

```
// The below code constructs the workbook and returns it
SXSSFWorkbook workBook = getWorkBook(fileName, excelData);
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName );
zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
workBook.write(new NonCloseableOutputStream(zos));
zos.closeEntry();
```